# Синхронизация таймеров шахматной партии

Tags: javascript, typescript, время, таймер

Пишу шахматную онлайн веб игру.
Столкнулся с тем что, не получается вычислить стартовое время таймеров с которого вести обратный счёт если партия уже начата. Дело в том что с сервера приходит время старта партии, а также список уже сделаных ходов(если страница была перезагружена или зашёл наблюдатель), каждый ход с временем смещения от старта партии, клиент синхронизирует время только на этапе загрузки. Из этого Получилось только вычислить статическое время таймера, **а время с тем отрезком который игрок думает мне не удается посчитать правильно**.
Моя идея была такова чтобы вычесть из текущего времени время последнего хода что даст то смещение от статического времени, далее проверить которой из сторон текущий ход и к времени хода это смещение прибавлять, но по какой то причине время начало плавать чего я бы не делал оно постоянно не соответствует действительному, Очень буду благодарен за любую информацию по синхронизации двух и более таймеров или описанию принципов синхронизации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как у вас игра фактически происходит на сервере, то просто передавайте время сервера.

```
        ┌─┐                                     ┌─┐   
        ║"│                                     ║"│   
        └┬┘                                     └┬┘   
        ┌┼┐                                     ┌┼┐   
         │              ┌──────┐                 │    
        ┌┴┐             │Server│                ┌┴┐   
      Player1           └──┬───┘              Player2 
         │  move(e2, e4)   │                     │    
         │────────────────>│                     │    
         │                 │                     │    
         │                 │────┐                     
         │                 │    │ time = getTime()    
         │                 │<───┘                     
         │                 │                     │    
         │      time       │                     │    
         │<─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ │                     │    
         │                 │                     │    
         │                 │  move(e2, e4, time) │    
         │                 │ ────────────────────>    
      Player1           ┌──┴───┐              Player2 
        ┌─┐             │Server│                ┌─┐   
        ║"│             └──────┘                ║"│   
        └┬┘                                     └┬┘   
        ┌┼┐                                     ┌┼┐   
         │                                       │    
        ┌┴┐                                     ┌┴┐
```

То есть, когда игрок делает ход на клиенте, ход ещё не заканчивается. Нужно какое-то время на передачу хода на сервер. И надо сообщить клиенту, что было на часах, когда ход прилетел на сервер. При таком подходе возможны лаги.

Например, я делаю движение мышкой в 12:00:00. Далее запрос летит на сервер 1 секунду. Получается, что я сделал ход в 12:00:01. Допустим ответ тоже летал по сети 1 секунду. Всё это время мои клиентские часы тикали и показывают 12:00:02. Однако, в ответе сервера время хода 12:00:01. Выходит мой соперник "думает" уже 1 секунду. При этом он может ещё и не получил мой ход.

Так как обычно сетевые задержки не так велики, то можно с этим смириться. Во многих сетевых играх бывают такие лаги при плохом пинге.

Comment: Как вы так быстро нарисовали такую красоту ?

Comment: @NastyStuffy https://www.planttext.com/

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ, он не совсем описал решение, но вы мне подсказали другой подход к решению и все получилось, Спасибо!